# python swap words using regex

Tags: python, regex, substitution

I am learning a lot of Regex today, but I'm already stuck at something.
I am trying to swap words using regex in python, but I can't seem to figure this out.

**Example**

```
s = 'How are you guys today'
# This is what I tried so far, but i obviously miss something 
# because this is giving an IndexError: no such group
re.sub(r'\w+\w+', r'\2\1', s)
```

**Expected result**

```
'are How guys you today'
```

Comment: You did not use any capturing groups in the pattern, `(...)`.

Comment: Just so you know: in general approach regex is not good tool to swap words, there are better methods.

Comment: @MaLiN2223 I know it is not the best approach this is just for learning purposes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use [**capturing groups**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and match non-word chars in between words:

```
import re
s = 'How are you guys today'
print(re.sub(r'(\w+)(\W+)(\w+)', r'\3\2\1', s))
# => are How guys you today
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/edZCtS)

The `(\w+)(\W+)(\w+)` pattern will match and capture 3 groups:

- `(\w+)`  - Group 1 (referred to with `\1` [**numbered backreference**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) from the replacement pattern): one or more word chars
- `(\W+)` - Group 2 (referred to with `\2`): one or more non-word chars
- `(\w+)`  - Group 3 (referred to with `\3`): one or more word chars

Comment: I added some more helpful links in bold.

Comment: @Ludisposed if it is an answer to your question please, mark is as such.

Comment: FYI: here is the [current regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MMU6Pr/2/). Just in case one wants to swap only words between whitespace, then use `(\w+)(\s+)(\w+)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/MMU6Pr/3)).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use groups to achieve this. You should also indicate spaces in your groups. The following outputs what you want.

```
s = 'How are you guys today'
re.sub(r'(\w+ )(\w+ )', r'\2\1', s)
```